# Nancy, First razor page not working

Tags: razor, nancy

I'm trying to get a first Razor template working with Nancy, and the first line of my .cshtml...

```
@inherits Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor.NancyRazorViewBase<dynamic>
```

gives me 3 build errors including the following...

```
'NancyContext' does not contain a definition for 'ApplicationInstance' and no extension method 'ApplicationInstance' accepting a first argument of type 'NancyContext' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

One very weird thing is that I have three "errors", but they're not stopping the build. They show in the Error list, the classes are underlined in red in the Solution explorer but not in the code window. Don't believe me ? Screenshot follows...
[image]

### Update

I've fixed the first two errors by adding explicit references to System.Web.Helpers and System.Web.WebPages. The remaining error, 'NancyContext' does not contain a definition for 'ApplicationInstance', is still bugging me. ApplicationInstance is a type in System.Web, for which I have a reference. If I delete the System.Web reference the project still builds. If I add the reference I still have the error.

Comment: Have you by any chance, solved the errors?

Comment: No. I fixed this by choosing "build only" in the dropdown on the left of the errors panel.

Answer (score 4):

I got the same error today and then noticed that the project was getting build in "Build + IntelliSense" mode (as in your screenshot), going to the dropdown their and building in "Build Only" mode resolved my errors!

Comment: This dropdown is in the Error List. I get the same "errors"; changing this setting does hide them. The errors only appear if the .cshtml file is open. My project uses OWIN and does not reference System.Web, which may be a factor.

Answer (score 0):

All I can say is that `ApplicationInstance` is not a Nancy type. Perhaps you are missing a namespace or assembly include? https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Razor-View-Engine

Other than that, you are going to have to share a lot more information or there's not much to go on

Comment: I'm v.happy to share information. But what to share? I've copied my content into a new project, and for the moment I'm getting the same "errors" but the project is building. I'd say this is likely a problem with the project templates I'm using. Thanks anyway.

Comment: To replicate, try creating a Nancy.Owin project in VS2015 that does not reference System.Web, and use the Razor view engine. Build the project with a .cshtml file open in the editor. Insure the Error List dropdown is set to Build + IntelliSense.