# Upgrading to Clint Eastwood caused some issues

Tags: nancy

I recently upgraded from barney rubble to clint eastwood and I ran into some issues. When using Nuget from VS to upgrade it did want to upgrade to Razor 3 which I allowed it.

I had to change the following from 2.0.0.0 to 3.0.0.0 in the web.config:

```
<sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
```

But I am unable to get it to work still. When trying to run i'm receiving a compilation error:

**Description:** An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

**Compiler Error Message:** CS1061: 'NancyContext' does not contain a definition for 'ApplicationInstance' and no extension method 'ApplicationInstance' accepting a first argument of type 'NancyContext' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

**Source Error:**

```
Line 34:         protected System.Web.HttpApplication ApplicationInstance {
Line 35:             get {
Line 36:                 return ((System.Web.HttpApplication)(Context.ApplicationInstance));
Line 37:             }
Line 38:         }
```

**Source File:** C:\Users\Jacob\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\0e4925d9\d5e47b7e\App_Web_login.cshtml.65a2d1ee.eydpkjxq.0.cs    Line: 36

I noticed i'm not the first to receive this error but the difference is the other person was seeing it in VS but it would still build... however with mine it will still build but it will not produce a page: [Nancy, First razor page not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36353303/nancy-first-razor-page-not-working)

Comment: As a test I manually removed Microsoft.AspNet.Razor 3.2.3 and put back version 2.0.30506 then it worked. When removing I noticed there was some other dependencies such as system.web.webpages.razor. I then upgraded Microsoft.AspNet.Razor back to 3.2.3 and now it is working. I did notice that I no longer has the other dll files in my references (such as system.web.webpages.razor). So somehow there was some sort of conflict.

Comment: Please add this comment as an answer to help others with the same problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a test I manually removed Microsoft.AspNet.Razor 3.2.3 and put back version 2.0.30506 then it worked. When removing I noticed there was some other dependencies such as system.web.webpages.razor. I then upgraded Microsoft.AspNet.Razor back to 3.2.3 and now it is working. I did notice that I no longer has the other dll files in my references (such as system.web.webpages.razor). So somehow there was some sort of conflict